# エンドポイント認証成功後も、毎回aiboクラウドへのリターンは必要か？

Tags: aibo-developer, aibo-visual-programming

エンドポイントの認証には既に成功しています。

これ以降は音声コマンドをaiboが認識すると、エンドポイントのプログラムがキックされると思います。
この際に検証に使った①「eventIdやchallenge」ではなく、②「deviceId、data、eventId、timestamp」がエンドポイントに飛びますよね？

【質問】
②の場合、エンドポイントのプログラムから、毎回aiboクラウドに対して何らかのリターン(など)は必要ですか？
それとも一度認証してしまえば、以降は特にリターン不要（認証で使った①challengeなどの受け取り・リターン部分のコードは除去可能）でしょうか？
※エンドポイント側では、aibo Web APIの行動制御を行おうとは思っていません。エンドポイントにあるサーバ側の処理を実行させようとしているだけです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo クラウドからデベロッパーのエンドポイントに対して送られる HTTP リクエストは、次の 2 つに分類できます。

- A. eventId が endpoint_verification の場合
- B. eventId が endpoint_verification 以外の場合

それぞれのリクエストに対しては、以下のように応答してください。

**A. eventId が endpoint_verification の場合**

エンドポイントの検証が行われる際に送られるリクエストです。
サーバーが正常にリクエストを処理できた場合には下記で応答してください。

> statusCode: 200
> body: challenge が含まれたJSON オブジェクト

現行仕様では、エンドポイントの検証リクエストがエンドポイントの登録時以外に送られることはありません。

詳しくは以下を参照してください

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%9D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%A4%9C%E8%A8%BC

```
エンドポイントから aibo クラウドへ送る検証用 HTTP リクエスト
レスポンスとして statusCode に 200 を、challege に送られて来た値を設定した body を作成し、返してください。
```

**B. eventId が endpoint_verification 以外の場合**

aibo からのイベントが通知される際に送られるリクエストです。
サーバーが正常にリクエストを処理できた場合には下記で応答してください。

> statusCode: 200

上記はいずれも現時点での仕様ですので、aibo Events API が更新された際はご確認ください。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: 承知しました！ありがとうございます！！